# OpenNI UserGenerator's hand position coordinates extremely jittery when compared to HandsGenerator

Tags: c++, tracking, kinect, openni

I'm using the Kinect and the OpenNI library to track a user's hands.

As far as I can see, there are two ways to do this; either using the [HandsGenerator](http://openni.org/docs2/Reference/classxn_1_1_hands_generator.html) and tracking each hand separately, or using [UserGenerator](http://openni.org/docs2/Reference/classxn_1_1_user_generator.html), and then asking for the hand positions using [`GetSkeletonJoint`](http://openni.org/docs2/Reference/classxn_1_1_skeleton_capability_a7d231c73542460bc5b2d6c7ec7bf06ac.html#a7d231c73542460bc5b2d6c7ec7bf06ac) and `XN_SKEL_LEFT_HAND`/`XN_SKEL_RIGHT_HAND`.

For various reasons, it'd be much more convenient if I could just use the `UserGenerator`, but the coordinates it gives me for the two hands are extremely jittery to the point of being unusable, even when setting a high smoothing value. In comparison, the coordinates given by `HandsGenerator` are very precise and stable.

How come the precision of the two methods is so different, and is there anything I can do to improve the precision of the coordinates given by the `UserGenerator` method?